# How to scroll between messages without returning to inbox/folder in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Let's say, in Gmail, that I'm already viewing a message. I would like to switch to viewing the next message in the inbox/folder (I don't know if the hotkeys will be different between the two) without having to go back to my inbox/folder and then choosing the next message manually. Is there any way to switch between messages directly without having to return to my inbox/folder every time?

Comment: Aha, I do.  Well, that was an embarrassingly easy solution to my problem. Is it even worth keeping my question for so simple and (should have been) obvious a solution?

Comment: Feel free to write up a formal answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @pnuts in the comments, you will find left/right arrows at the top right of Gmail (next to the Settings gear, as shown below).

[image: left/right arrows at the top right of Gmail]

As a side note, you may also use keyboard shortcuts to go faster:

- press <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the next message
- press <kbd>k</kbd> to go to the previous message

Comment: @al-e : Thanks for the edit, I didn't know about the keyboard tag. Using 'message' instead of 'email' though goes against Gmail's definitions: the proper term according to Gmail here would be 'conversation', which can contain several 'messages' (replies, forwards etc.). You may use 'p' and 'n' to navigate those. I'll agree that most readers won't see the difference.

Comment: Then edit and fix.